# I am receiving data from event hub at second level. i want to transform that second level data to minute level. What query should I write for that?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

**Input data is something like**

59409122452613044868884217206482057377,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:00,2016-04-06 20:00:01,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
263649234702986406671448423011884327516,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:01,2016-04-06 20:00:02,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
45230206674391617469323788546714891648,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:02,2016-04-06 20:00:03,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
279010763836525463474142095392007675007,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:03,2016-04-06 20:00:04,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
167873679971561615738619632383957198735,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:04,2016-04-06 20:00:05,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
35497058475986648042007359340702916856,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:05,2016-04-06 20:00:06,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
337876088861193510875869019453151763828,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:06,2016-04-06 20:00:07,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
47217330213199917248090863159093904302,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:07,2016-04-06 20:00:08,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
55098260101235798009761365494917919250,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:08,2016-04-06 20:00:09,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
89164749756298354981381333891783302288,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:09,2016-04-06 20:00:10,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
299812905942114176730968658457034871141,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:10,2016-04-06 20:00:11,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
239017369564517842658599624185907604126,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:11,2016-04-06 20:00:12,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2
292106920572693590741235795986008625826,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:12,2016-04-06 20:00:13,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2

**and I Want to convert these records to minute level like**
59409122452613044868884217206482057377,432221432,2016-04-06 20:00:00,2016-04-06 20:00:13,Channel 4,The Supervet,2016-04-06 20:00:00.0000000,2016-04-06 20:00:20.0000000,LIVE,LIVE,News,Documentary,1000,,The Supervet - Series 7,-2

Answer (score 0):

*Eventhub is a service to ingest data. It will egress the same data whatever you will write into it.*

**Now if you want to get a minute level data, you can have two options:**

1. Ingest minute level of data into eventhub directly. **or**
2. Aggregate the second level data to minute level of data using some background job like Azure Web Job.